# Optional form's name parameter passed to a sub

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hello. I have a small problem and I can't figure it out: how can I create an optional parameter for a form's name? For example I want to do something like this:

```
    Private Sub Draw(ByVal Start_Pos As Point, ByVal End_Pos As Point, Optional ByVal Form_Name As Form = Cube)


    End Sub
```

**I'm not sure if what I want is possible**.I just know that the code is not correct because I must specify to the program that "Cube" is a form not just a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant value is required for Optional params.

When a constant value is not possible to establish at design time for whatever reason, then the easiest trick is to set the vaue as `Nothing` and check if the value is nothing inside the block, if it is, then set their default value at execution time.

An example:

```
Private Sub Draw(ByVal startPos As Point, ByVal endPos As Point, 
                 Optional ByVal form As Form = Nothing)

    If (form Is Nothing) Then
        form = Cube
    End If

    ' ...

End Sub
```

An adaptation to the real problem that you'd described:

```
Private Sub Draw(ByVal startPos As Point, ByVal endPos As Point, 
                 Optional ByVal formName As String = "")

    If ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(formName) ) Then
        formName = Cube.Name
    End If

    ' ...

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a problem..When i try accessing an control from Cube form with this code: ...... form=Cube.....form.Frame.Image=... it doesn't work. It says that 'Frame' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Form ., Frame is a picturebox.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in documents for [Optional Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yx51zh.aspx) for each optional parameter, you must specify a constant expression as the default value of that parameter.

So you can't use a form instance as default value for optional parameter.

If you need to set a form name as default value for your `string` optional parameter:

You can set one of your application forms full name (including namespace) as default value and then create an instance of that form using [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Unwrap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap(v=vs.110).aspx) the object and use [`DirectCast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) to cast it to form and show it later.

To create other forms that their names passed as that parameter, you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` also you can have a `Dictionary(Of String, Type)` containing names and form types or `Dictionary(Of String, Form)` containing names and form instances and use this dictionary to get the instance of form.